# Trying to select image - Put it on colored background. Photoshop CC 2015 Windows (Pictures included)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, background-removal

I am attempting to take an image and put it on a different color background.  On Monday I paid $100 for classes.  The GREEN & WHITE backgrounds were just examples.  I want to select and choose colors.

But if someone could help now.  Or shoot me a link or FAQ.  Here are my steps and photos. I realize you can not read the writing on the images but they follow the steps in order L**eft to right & Top to bottom.**  Please do not worry about the writing on the pictures.

- Step 1 Pictures do have bad lighting & are poor quality (I know)
- Step 2: Pressed Control J Made Background layer. Used Magnetic Lass to outline image.  Outline done image selected  The 3 new layers marked with Line.
- Step3 I was hoping copied and pasted my image.  Instead outline only. (When I control C it is not copying the image.  It is copying the outline only, what am I doing wrong?)
- Step 4 Proof I can change background colors on layers  - GREEN
- Step 5 PROOF IT WORKS SOMETIMES :) !!!!!

**Where am I making my mistake?**  I need to invert my image, where and when?  IS THERE a FAQ on this?  I searched for VIDEOS found none.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I compiled a little tutorial for you. My Interface language is Polish, but I'll translate the commands to English version, so no worries!

1. Using Pen Tool (hotkey: P), make a path around the object you wish to select. However, there are other other options of making selections, but this one is the most accurate, effective (and thus time-consuming), by far!

[image]

Then right-click in the path area and select "Make selection".

[image]

Then, use the "Feather" option and set it to 0.5px.

2. Now that you have your selection:

[image]

Select Marquee Tool (hotkey: M) and right-click on your selected area.

[image]

Then, select the Layer by copying.

3. Now that you have your bag removed from the background, create a new layer (hotkey: ctrl + shift + N), name it w/e you like, but keep it simple.

[image]

4. It's time to create another layer and stack it above our cut-out bag.

[image]

Remember to put them in proper order of display in order to make it colorful and put the focus on the bag (or w/e thing you wish to highlight).

5. Viola!

[image]